# C++ Object Variables

Tags: c++

I'm trying to assign a variable or attribute of an object in C++ and am unsure as to how to do this.

```
class ClassA{
public:
    double a,b,c,d,e,f;
};

ClassA * example = new ClassA;
example.a =.01;
```

Why do I need to include the '*' in defining the object 'example' (I got this through another tutorial). How do I correct this to correctly set the values of a, b, c, d, e, f for the object 'example'

Comment: Please read a better `C++` tutorial. You seem to be missing the absolute basics of this language.

Comment: What are you trying to assign the variables to? The * is the dereferencing operator, which means you're creating a variable which points to the location in memory where the object you want exists:  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/  You might want to start with the www.cplusplus.com site and work through some of the tutorials there.

Comment: @MauriceReeves There is no de-reference operator in OP's code. I worry you might be confusing them more than they already are :-)

Comment: LOL.  Yeah probably.  Was trying to get the terminology right, but might have muddied the waters further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
ClassA example;
example.a =.01;
```

You were using pointers in your code, and it looks like you need practice with other ideas before starting with pointers.

Comment: Or `ClassA example = {0.01};`

Comment: It says unknown type name 'example' for Drew's comment

Comment: hmm...it is still saying unknown type name 'example'

Comment: @user3681670 You need to put the code in this answer inside of a function. Statements cannot go outside of functions.

Comment: @user3681670 I think you're being cheated by the awful tutorial you found.  Find a new tutorial.  We can't tell you why your mystery tutorial is doing such a poor job.

Comment: Ok thanks. I see your response worked. Can you advise on what the following would mean: if I'm not going to use pointers (and hence its not truly OOP), then I can just use C instead of C++

Comment: @user3681670 I'm glad it worked!  Yes, I can advise - that's a bunch of nonsense.  Where are you getting this awful information?

Comment: Someone I was working with made the comment (I don' think they were trying to be negative per se). Anyway, given how popular this question was I may need to focus on the basics more lol

Comment: @user3681670 The only reason why pointers would be better is for inheritance purposes, but even then I would recommend references.

Comment: @user3681670 as someone already commented, [you should take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  And then share that link with your coworkers.  I don't think your coworker was being negative either, but that coworker is **feeding you some very bad information**.

Comment: @user3681670 It should be the other way around. If you're going to use pointers everywhere you might as well use C instead of C++. But it sounds like you're getting advice from people without a clue.